# Laravel 5.8 - validação de multiplos arquivos ex.video

Tags: php, html5, laravel, laravel-5.8

Estou utilizando o  multiple para inserir mais de um arquivo, mas não estou conseguindo validar o tamanho e o formato quando é inserido um ou mais videos.

form:

```
<input type="file" name="anexo3[]" class="form-control @error('anexo3') is-invalid @enderror"  multiple >
```

a validação que estou usando:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [

           'anexo3' =>  ['mimes:mp4,mov,ogg,qt','max:2000']

       ];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando o validate do Laravel.

```
   $request->validate([
        'anexo' => 'required',
        'anexo.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg',
        'anexo.*' => 'max:2000'
    ]);
```